# Adding a computed default value to Django model, how?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to learn Python and Django by implementing an online forum. Right now, I'm trying to set the default value of the post title to "Re:" + thread.title, but I can't seem to do it.

I've searched for anything like this but nothing seems to answer my problem.

Here's my code (models.py):

```
from django.db import models

class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'[id=%s]%s' % (self.id, self.title)

class Post(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Post, self).__init__()
        if not self.title:
            self.title = "Re: %s" % self.thread.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s::[id=%s]%s' % (self.thread, self.id, self.title)
```

I hope someone can help me.

Regards,
Chad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set the default value in the overridden `save` method. Your `__init__` code doesn't work because at that point `self.thread` is not set yet.

Comment: Thanks wRAR. I'm curious would this be evident when adding things via the admin page?

Comment: @Chad no, but you don't have many other options, as `self.thread` is initially empty when creating object in admin.